# Get a list of files present in a folder

Tags: windows, command-prompt

I want the names of the files present in a folder . Is there any command in command prompt or any other way that can list all the file name(only file name and its extension) that are present in a particular folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dir does what you want, you may want to add /B to only get filename and extension.

```
dir /B
```

Full options of dir can be viewed by

```
dir /?
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `dir /B` that should give you the expected result.